# What is the difference between INNER JOIN and ANTI JOIN

Tags: sql, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am absolutely confused by the join terminology in PySpark. I will list how I understand two of these joins, I just want to know if my understanding is correct, since I find the documentation more confusing than helpful.

We start with two dataframes: `dfA` and `dfB`.

```py
dfA.join(dfB, 'user', 'inner')
```

means join just the rows where `dfA` and `dfB` have common elements on the user column. (intersection of A and B on the user column).

```py
dfA.join(dfB, 'user', 'leftanti')
```

means construct a dataframe with elements in `dfA` **THAT ARE NOT** in `dfB`.

Are these two correct?

Comment: your understanding is correct.even better, run it on sample data and check the outputs.

Comment: yep, done that. I am just getting funny results from my database, so I wanted to make sure at least I knew what I was talking about. Thanks. If anyone wants, you can maybe write a more detailed answer about joins (some examples maybe) and I will accept the answer.

Comment: can you show what the *funny results* are?

Comment: For example I have a dataset, let's call it actions_night, and another one, actions_day. If I do a leftanti join of actions_night with actions_day, I get 0. It is impossible that there was not a single user seen only during the night.

Comment: why do you say it is impossible?

Comment: I'd suggest that you create test scenarios. We can't help you with the information that you are sharing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

inner join => if DFB does not have record for DFA then it does not return non-matched records.

left anti => most close to Not Exists

```
-- NOT EXISTS
SELECT *
FROM dfA
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM dfB
  WHERE dfA.DeptName = dfB.DeptName
)
```

also LEFT OUTER JOIN equivalent

```
SELECT * 
FROM dfA
LEFT OUTER JOIN DFB
  ON dfA.DeptName = dfB.DeptName
where dfB.DeptName IS NULL;
```